# Apply class to a column after date comparison in AngularJS + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, twitter-bootstrap-3

Following is the type of date I am getting from db - `2015-07-15T18:30:00.000Z` . Now I am trying to add bootstap class `btn-info` if this date is 1 year before current date (Date.now()), if its less than or equals to 1 year but less than 3 months from current date then add class `btn-warning`, for 3 months or less add class `btn-danger`.

For this I am using `ng-class` on my field, like -
  `ng-class="calDateDiff(exp_date)"`

In `calDateDiff()` method, I am trying to do the conversion, but unable to know which type of date format its represents.

I checked UTC in Js but its not that, also I tried `Date.parse(Date.now())` but unable to know the format.

```
$scope.calDatediff = function(exp_date) {
  // exp_date - Date.now()
  // Here in calculation I am also not sure 
  // to handle leap years
}
```

Please let me know what type of date format is this and what is the right approach to handle this.

FYI- I don't want to use `Moment.js` as this is to be applied for only one column field, so it will be overhead just for one column to show.

**EDIT 1 -**

Ok I got this as its an ISO string -

so for current date I believe its going to be -

current date - `new Date().toISOString()`

let me know how I cam going to compare these two strings for an year, or 3 month condition ?

Comment: Don't work with strings, work with the `Date` object. You'll see that it will be less troubling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new date object and subtract.

```
Date.now() - new Date('2015-07-15T18:30:00.000Z')
1557113984
```

if you want to know if a year has elapsed one way to do it is to increment the date you got from the database and see if it is less than the current date:

```
var dbDate = new Date('2015-07-15T18:30:00.000Z');

dbDate
Wed Jul 15 2015 11:30:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

dbDate.setMonth(dbDate.getMonth() + 12);
1468607400000

dbDate
Fri Jul 15 2016 11:30:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

dbDate < Date.now()
false
```

Comment: but how do I find an year(considering leap year case) difference correctly from this ?

Comment: I think here `dbDate.getMonth() + 12` it should be 11 instead of 12 as I checked docs and its saying 0-11 month range

Answer (score 1):

That seems to me like an ISOString date. All you need to do is create a new object of type `Date` by passing that string to the constructor:

```
var dbDate = new Date("2015-07-15T18:30:00.000Z");
```

This will give you a Date object with which you can work with and easily compare it to `Date.now();` I think you can do the rest of it by yourself.

Here's more info about `Date`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: but how do I find an year(considering leap year case) difference correctly ?

Comment: If you will have a look over the `MDN` documentation about `Date`, you will see that there is a method called `getFullYear`, which will return you the year, e.g. for `Date.now()` it will return `2015`.